# Print the relative path

Tags: code-golf

**Description**

Given a source path and a destination path, output the relative path to the destination with respect to the source.

**Rules**

1. The input can come from stdin or as arguments to the program/function.
2. Both Windows and Unix style paths must be supported.
3. The output path can use `/` and/or `\` for the path separator (your choice and combination of both is OK).
4. You can assume a relative path is possible.
5. The use of external programs, built-in or library functions made for computing relative paths is prohibited (e.g. Python's `os.path.relpath`)
6. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

   *Edit:* New rule from comments.
7. The relative path must be the shortest relative path possible.
8. Assume the destination path is different from the source path.

**Example 1**

```
# In
/usr/share/geany/colorschemes
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin

# Out
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
```

**Example 2**

```
# In
C:\Windows\System32\drivers
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

# Out
..\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Comment: Regarding rule #3 - is a mixture ok? E.g. `../../vim\vim73\ftplugin`.

Comment: Do we have to return the shortest relative path or is it okay to yield any path?

Comment: @Duncan Yes, a mix is ok.

Comment: @Howard, it must be the shortest relative path.

Comment: shouldn't the first example be `../vim/vim73/ftplugin`?

Comment: @Martijn If you were in the `colorschemes` directory, `cd ../vim/vim73/ftplugin` would take you to `/usr/share/geany/vim/vim73/ftplugin`

Comment: What about same paths? Are we going to output `./`, `.` or nothing? Do we have to handle different drives on M$ like `C:\Windows` and `D:\Games`? If so what will be the output? `/d D:\Games`??? Is it OK to print `../../../../usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin`?

Comment: OK. I just saw rule #7, but my other questions still stand. And how about `~`? Should our program/function handle home dirs in *nix and `%windir%`(environment variables in M$) as they could be the shortest path?

Comment: @core1024 I think rule #4 addresses the issue of paths on different drives; since there is not a relative path, don't worry about it. There is no way of knowing what the absolute paths of `~` and `%windir%` are, so ignore those. I'll add a rule to assume that the paths are different.

Comment: @core1024 Thanks! The question was inspired by some real work that I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 46 bytes

```
ll]{'\/'/f/:~}/W{)__3$=4$@==}g@,1$-"../"*o>'/*
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Examples

```
$ echo '/usr/share/geany/colorschemes
> /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin' | cjam path.cjam; echo
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
$ echo 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0' | cjam path.cjam; echo
../WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
```

#### How it works

```
ll]         " Read two lines from STDIN and wrap them in an array.                       ";
{           " For each line:                                                             ";
  '\/       " Split by “\”.                                                              ";
  '/f/      " Split each chunk by “/”.                                                   ";
  :~        " Flatten the array of chunks.                                               ";
}/          "                                                                            ";
W           " Push -1 (accumulator).                                                     ";
{           "                                                                            ";
  )__       " Increment and duplicate twice.                                             ";
  3$=       " Extract the corresponding chunk from the first line.                       ";
  4$@=      " Extract the corresponding chunk from the second line.                      ";
  =         " If the are equal,                                                          ";
}g          " repeat the loop.                                                           ";
@,          " Rotate the array of chunks of the first line on top and get its length.    ";
1$-         " Subtract the value of the accumulator.                                     ";
"../"*o     " Print the string “../” repeated that many times.                           ";
>           " Remove all chunks with index less than the accumulator of the second line. ";
'/*         " Join the chunks with “/”.                                                  ";
```

Comment: It has a bug. Try `/aa/x` with `/ab/y`.

Comment: @user23013: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 116

Here's a shell script to get the ball rolling.  Pretty sure there'll be shorter answers:

```
n=`cmp <(echo $1) <(echo $2)|grep -Po "\d+(?=,)"`
printf -vs %`grep -o /<<<${1:n-1}|wc -l`s
echo ${s// /../}${2:n-1}
```

Output:

```
$ ./rel.sh /usr/share/geany/colorschemes /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin
../vim/vim73/ftplugin
$ ./rel.sh /usr/share/geany/colorschemes/ /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin/
$ ./rel.sh /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin /usr/share/geany/colorschemes
../../geany/colorschemes
$
```

Note there is no way for the script to tell if the string `ftplugin` is a file or a directory.  You may explicitly provide a directory by appending it with an `/` as in the example above.

Won't handle paths containing whitespace or other funny characters.  Not sure if that is a requirement or not.  Just a few extra quotes would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby >= 1.9, 89 <del>94</del> characters

```
$;=/\\|\//
a,b=$*.map &:split
puts"../"*(a.size-r=a.index{a[$.+=1]!=b[$.]}+1)+b[r..-1]*?/
```

Input via command line arguments. Works for both UNIX- and Windows-style paths, including paths with repeated folder names:

```
$ ruby relpath.rb /usr/share/geany/colorschemes /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
$ ruby relpath.rb 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers' 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'
../WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
$ ruby relpath.rb /foo/bar/foo/bar /foo/qux/foo/bar
../../../qux/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (E6) 104

*Edit* Added alert for output

```
R=(s,d)=>alert(s.split(x=/\/|\\/).map(a=>a==d[0]?d.shift()&&'':'../',d=d.split(x)).join('')+d.join('/'))
```

**Ungolfed**

```
R (s,d) => // a single espression is returned, no {} or () needed
  s.split(x=/\/|\\/) // split string at / or \, save regexp in X for later
  .map( // create a new array from s
     a => a == d[0] // check if current of s and d equals
          ? d.shift() && '' // map to '' and cut 1 element of d
          : '../', // else map to '../'
     d=d.split(x)) // second param of map is useless, so split d here
  .join('')+d.join('/') // join map and concat to rest of d adding separators
```

**Test**

```
R('C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers','C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0')
```

> ../WindowsPowerShell/v1.0

```
R('/usr/share/geany/colorschemes','/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin')
```

> ../../vim/vim73/ftplugin

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <strike>69</strike> 66

I didn't post this one because I thought someone must be able to do it much better. But apparently it is not that easy.

```
sed -r 'N;s/(.*[/\])(.*)\n\1/\2\n/'|sed '1s/[^/\]*/../g;N;s!\n!/!'
```

`N` makes `sed` match two lines together. The first expression removes the common prefix ending with `/` or `\`. The second expression replaces directory names with `..` in the first line. Finally it concatenates the two lines with the separator.

Thanks to Hasturkun for 3 characters.

Comment: Looks interesting!  Can you add an explanation?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Added. But basically they are just regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to play with this next time I'm at a terminal

Comment: You don't really need to run `sed` twice, you can do this with a single script.

Comment: @Hasturkun But I didn't find a way to have it work with `N`. Maybe you can edit this answer if you know how.

Comment: Single sed instance, 67 chars. `sed -r 'N;s!(.*)(.*)\n\1!\2/\n!;:a;s![^/\]*[/\]\n!\n../!;ta;s/\n//'`. You should also note that you don't need to double backslashes in character lists, and that your first `[/\\]` is redundant.

Comment: @Hasturkun ``[/\\]`` is not redundant. Try `/aa/x` with `/ab/y`. But at least I have removed those backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

## J - 63 char

A function taking the old path on the left and the new path on the right.

```
}.@;@(c=.c&}.`(,~(<'/..')"0)@.(~:&{.))&('/'<;.1@,'\/'&charsub)~
```

This solution comes in three parts, looking like `post@loop&pre~`. Explained by explosion:

```
post @ loop & pre ~   NB. the full golf
                  ~   NB. swap the arguments: new on left, old on right
            & pre     NB. apply pre to each argument
       loop           NB. run the recursive loop on both
post @                NB. apply post to the final result

'/'<;.1@,'\/'&charsub  NB. pre
         '\/'&charsub  NB. replace every \ char with /
'/'     ,              NB. prepend a / char
   <;.1@               NB. split string on the first char (/)

c=.c&}.`(,~(<'/..')"0)@.(~:&{.)  NB. loop
                      @.(~:&{.)  NB. if the top folders match:
    &}.                          NB.   chop off the top folders
   c                             NB.   recurse
       `                         NB. else:
           (<'/..')"0            NB.   change remaining old folders to /..
         ,~                      NB.   append to front of remaining new folders
c=.                              NB. call this loop c to recurse later

}.@;  NB. post
   ;  NB. turn the list of folders into a string
}.@   NB. chop off the / in the front
```

Note that we add a leading `/` to each path before splitting, so that we handle Windows-style paths by making `C:` into a "folder". This results in an empty folder at the start of Unix-style paths, but that always gets removed by the loop.

See it in action:

```
   NB. you can use it without a name if you want, we will for brevity
   relpath =. }.@;@(c=.c&}.`(,~(<'/..')"0)@.(~:&{.))&('/'<;.1@,'\/'&charsub)~
   '/usr/share/geany/colorschemes' relpath '/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin'
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
   'C:\Windows\System32\drivers' relpath 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'
../WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
```

You can also try it yourself at [tryj.tk](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=%27%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Ffoo%2Fbar%27%20%28relpath%20%3D%3A%20%7D.%40%3B%40%28c%3D.c%26%7D.%60%28%2C~%28%3C%27%2F..%27%29%220%29%40.%28~%3A%26%7B.%29%29%26%28%27%2F%27%3C%3B.1%40%2C%27%5C%2F%27%26charsub%29~%29%20%27%2Ffoo%2Fqux%2Ffoo%2Fbar%27).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby - 89

```
r=/\/|\\/
s = ARGV[0].split r
d = ARGV[1].split r
puts ("../"*(s-d).size)+((d-s).join"/")
```

Usage:

```
ruby relative.rb working/directory destination/directory
```

Comment: This fails for arguments like `/foo/bar/foo/bar` and `/foo/qux/foo/bar`.

Comment: And fails for windows style paths

Comment: @edc65 The rules don't say it's necessary to support both path formats, you can do either one.

Comment: @nderscore Rule 2 Both Windows and Unix style paths must be supported.

Comment: @Ventero thanks for noticing that, but it's a bug that's in the nature of this method. I don't think it can be fixed without totally changing the answer.

Comment: @Jwosty: Well, that's the beauty, isn't it? Coming up with a solution that's both short *and* correct. I have in the past had cases where I had to revise the answer completely because of an overlooked edge case. Now, in this case I do put the blame partly on the task as well, because I believe a solid set of test cases should accompany every task, but well.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 120

```py
a,b=(i.split('\\/'['/'in i])for i in map(input,'  '))
while[]<a[:1]==b[:1]:del a[0],b[0]
print('../'*len(a)+'/'.join(b))
```

Example:

```
$ python3 path.py
 /usr/share/geany/colorschemes
/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin 
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
```

Comment: Might there be a shorter way to do line 1 with `exec` and string operations?

Comment: @xnor Maybe, but I can't see it.

Comment: Might `map(input,'  ')` work for `(input(),input())? (I can't test it myself)

Comment: @xnor Yeah that works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>119</strike> 106

```
void p(char*s,char* d){while(*s==*d){s++;d++;}s--;while(*s){if(*s==47||*s==92)printf("../");s++;}puts(d);}
```

Comment: `p(char*s,char*d){for(;*s;)*s++-*d?*s-47||printf("../"):d++;puts(d);}` 68 chars w/o backslash

Comment: Thanks! But rule 2 says both must be supported. It is in the output where I can pick one or the other(rule 3).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 155

```
function p(s,d){s=s.split(/\\|\//g);d=d.split(/\\|\//g);o=[];for(i=0;s[i]==d[i];i++);for(j=s.length-i;j--;)o[j]="..";return o.concat(d.slice(i)).join("/")}
```

Parses either path format but outputs with `/` separator.

```
console.log(p("/usr/share/geany/colorschemes","/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin"));
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin
console.log(p("/usr/share/geany/colorschemes/test/this","/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/this/is/a/test"));
../../../../vim/vim73/ftplugin/this/is/a/test
console.log(p("c:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\etc\\host","c:\\windows\\system\\drivers\\etc\host"));
../../../../system/drivers/etchost
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>158</strike> 151

```
function r($a,$b){$a=explode('/',$a);$b=explode('/',$b);foreach($a as $k=>$v){if($v==$b[$k])$b[$k]='..';else break;}unset($b[0]);echo implode('/',$b);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
function r($a,$b){
    $a=explode('/',$a);
    $b=explode('/',$b);
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){
        if($v==$b[$k])$b[$k]='..';
        else break; 
    }
    unset($b[0]);
    echo implode('/',$b);
}
// these lines are not included in count:
r('/test/test2/abc','/test/test3/abcd'); // ../test3/abcd
r('/test/test2/abc','/test/test2/abcd'); // ../../abcd
```

Comment: Your answer isn't correct. Try making this dirs and `cd` form one to another :)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 144 chars

One solution:

```
x=args[0][1]!=':'?'/':'\\'
f={args[it].tokenize x}
s=f 0
d=f 1
n=0
while(s[n]==d[n++]);
u="..$x"*(s.size-(--n))
println "$u${d.drop(n).join x}"
```

example output:

```
bash$ groovy P.groovy C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0
..\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

bash$ groovy P.groovy /usr/share/geany/colorschemes /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin
../../vim/vim73/ftplugin

bash$ groovy P.groovy /foo/bar/foo/bar /foo/qux/foo/bar
../../../qux/foo/bar
```

ungolfed:

```
// fs = file seperator, / or \
fs = args[0][1]!=':'?'/':'\\'

s = args[0].tokenize fs
d = args[1].tokenize fs

// n = # of matching dirs from root + 1
n = 0
while (s[n] == d[n++]) ;

// up = the up-prefix. e.g. "../../..", for instance 
n--
up = "..${fs}" * (s.size-n)

println "$up${d.drop(n).join fs}"
```